# How do I put prime numbers into a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have written a piece of code below, that asks for a user input and checks whether it is prime or not. I want to build on this now, so when the user inputs a number, I count the number of primes up to this number and display. For example, if the user enters 10, my program will output 'there are 4 primes'. My thinking is that I have to store each prime number into a vector, but my question is how?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <double> primeHolder
    int x, i, flag;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer ";
    cin >> x;

    for (i = 2; i <= x/2; i++)
    {
        if(x%i == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
        cout << "This is a prime number";
    else
        cout << "This is not a prime number";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a loop and `push_back(x)`?

Comment: First of all, `x/2` is a bit too much (use `i <= sqrt(x)`). Secondly, [eratosthene's sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is much more efficient (especially if in a boolean mask you only hold odd numbers per bit and even more when you increase the wheel size). Thirdly, [**push_back()**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) is what you need.

Comment: You can do it much faster with a chance of `1 / (2^100)` to be wrong, using Fermat's primality test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it makes sense to define an `isPrime()` function to make your code more readable:

```
bool isPrime(int x)
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= x/2; i++)
    {
        if(x%i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can write your `main()` in the following way:

```
int main()
{
    int input;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> input;

    // You deal with integers here, so you shouldn't use vector<double>.
    // As all numbers are positive, you could also use unsigned int.
    vector<int> primeHolder;
    for(int i = 2; i <= input; i++)
    {
        // Test all values that are not larger than the input value.
        if(isPrime(i))
        {
            // If the tested value is a prime, append it to the vector.
            primeHolder.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    cout << "There are " << primeHolder.size() << " primes:" << endl;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < primeHolder.size(); j++)
    {
        // Print every prime number that was stored in the vector.
        // You can access vector elements similar to an array,
        // but you can also use iterators.
        cout << primeHolder[j] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives the following output for your example input:

> Enter a positive integer: 10
>   There are 4 primes:
>   2
>   3
>   5
>   7

Note: The code above is rather inefficient. If you want to handle large inputs, you should look for a smarter algorithm, e.g. the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), as mentioned by @theoden in the comments.

If you want to learn more about the capabilities of the `vector` class template, please have a look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). The documentation also contains example code.

Comment: Thank you Honk! Just what I was looking for. Just one quick question, when you use for(size_t j=0; .....  I would have thought you would have to declare j as an int? or does size_t do this for us? cheers :)

Comment: The `size()` function of the `vector` provides a value of type `size_t`. This is an unsigned value. If I use `int` for `j`, then my compiler gives me a warning that there is a conflict between `signed` and `unsigned`. So, if you use `size_t`, you are on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks Honk! very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

In an if statement where you find out that it is a prime number, simply add it to the vector.

Small Sample Code:

```
if(x is prime)
{
    primeHolder.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tarik, but what is 'push_back(x)' here?

Comment: That's how you add/insert a thing into a vector. You can read about all the functionalities of a vector here - [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), Look specifically for push_back

Comment: right ok, so that would fill the vectors with prime numbers. Now if i want to print this vector I just use cout << primeHolder    ?

Comment: @FrankWhite Please refer to a book or tutorial, Stack Overflow isn't meant as a tutoring site.

Comment: @FrankWhite It is very simple to type on google, "How to print out a vector c++". You shouldn't need to create a thread on here. You could have just as easily googled for "How to add to a vector" or something similar.

Comment: I didnt create a thread to specifically print out a vector, as the title suggests. I asked it in the comments, but in the future will google for what seems to be simple questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the vector contains prime numbers it is much better to determine the next prime number by dividing the current number by elements in the vector.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        std::vector<unsigned int> primes;

        if ( n >= 2 ) primes.push_back( 2 );

        for ( unsigned int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2 )
        {
            if ( std::all_of( primes.begin(), primes.end(), std::bind1st( std::modulus<unsigned int>(), i ) ) )
            {
                primes.push_back( i );
            }
        }

        if ( !primes.empty() )
        {
            std::cout << "There are the following prime numbers up to " << n << ": ";
            for ( unsigned int x : primes ) std::cout << x << ' ';
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "There are no prime numbers up to " << n << std::endl;
        }           
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter sequentially the following numbers

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 0
```

then the program output will look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 10
There are the following prime numbers up to 10: 2 3 5 7 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 20
There are the following prime numbers up to 20: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 30
There are the following prime numbers up to 30: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 40
There are the following prime numbers up to 40: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 50
There are the following prime numbers up to 50: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 60
There are the following prime numbers up to 60: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 70
There are the following prime numbers up to 70: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 80
There are the following prime numbers up to 80: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 90
There are the following prime numbers up to 90: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 100
There are the following prime numbers up to 100: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```